# Is it mandatory to have a variable in awk's first statement?

Tags: ubuntu, awk, mawk

I am having some hard time with awk today. If I try to do:

```
df|awk '{print $2; $some=$2; print $some}'
```

It works as expected and I get the size of the disks twice but if I do:

```
df|awk '{$some=$2; print $some}'
```

I just get blank lines. Why is this happening? Something is maybe wrong in my understanding but why the usage of a field mandatory for subsequent fields to work? I also tried doing:

```
df|awk '{print "hello"; $some=$2; print $some}'
```

and I got some "hello", each separated by a newline. Where is $some=$2 lost?

My `df` command outputs:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5       38448788 32098732   4396932  88% /
udev             1914564        4   1914560   1% /dev
tmpfs             768744      984    767760   1% /run
```

Comment: Can you post the output of your df command?

Comment: @Guru I have added the output of df.

Comment: `$some` in `awk` means field number some. (e.g. if some=13, then $some means 13th field)

Comment: Okay. Then how come first statement is working fine?

Comment: @AdityaPatawari : I get correct results when I try in cygwin or linux...which OS and shell are you in?

Comment: No idea. All your codes work correctly for me: the first displays each `$2` twice, the second displays each `$2`, the third displays “hello” followed by `42` on separate line for each `$2`.

Comment: Are you sure it's not `awk '{some=$2; print $some}'`

Comment: @manatwork, I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I just installed gawk from the repository and now it works fine.

Comment: `df|awk '{some=$2; print some}'` works as expected (Fedora 18)

Comment: @vonbrand yes. It was something really stupid that Ubuntu did. It ships with mawk instead of gawk. Once I installed gawk, it has started working fine.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use the `$`-sign in front of `some`. What happens is that with your first command  `$2` gets printed and then `$some=$2` translates to `$0=$2` since `some` is unitialized (in some `awk` implementations `some` gets converted from `""` to `0`, not all (then you get an error message)), so you are replacing the record (`$0`) with `$2`. Then you print `$some`, which means `$0`
So it is identical to

```
df|awk '{print $2; $0=$2; print $0}'
```

and

```
df|awk '{$0=$2; print $0}'
```

What you probably meant to do was:

```
df|awk '{print $2; some=$2; print some}'
```

Comment: I did try this before but it gave me an error: `awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767`

Comment: @AdityaPatawari: Then what I suspect you did was: `df|awk '{print $2; some=$2; print $some}'` which would try to create field $38448788 with your sample input.

Comment: that is quite possible.

Answer (score 1):

I get the expected result.  The first command prints each item twice.  The second command prints it once.

This is rather unconventional - "some" will have the value of zero by default since it is undefined.  $some is therefore $0, which represents the entire line, so basically you are replacing the line with whatever you find in $2 when you use `$some=$2`

Compare it with this result:

```
johan@computer:~$ df|awk '{$some=$2; print}'
1K-blocks
30827524
4041028
1621692
5120
4054228
102400
4054228
60555340
209548784
```

Why would you not get any output or a different result:  I expect the behaviour of using uninitiated variables to be potentially undefined, at least on some systems.

On Solaris I have access to the "standard" awk as well as the supposedly POSIX compliant version installed in /usr/xpg4/bin/awk.  Both of these produce the same result for the following

They produce varying results depending on whether I add print "hello" in front or not, and depending on whether I replace the last command with "print" (in stead of print $some) or not.

All of them print SOMETHING, not blanks, though - I have not managed to find a version that reproduces that effect.

So I expect this to be some kind of undefined behaviour due to using an un-initialized variable - **you are assigning a value to a column, which is potentially far past the end of the possible range of columns** in the input stream.  $some refers to a column identified by the value of "some"

You should just use "some" as variable, eg

```
df | awk '{print "hello";some=$2; print some}'
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the reason this happened is because Ubuntu does not use the standard GNU implantation but something else known as mawk which breaks a lot of code which worked under standard unix.

Please refer to this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=619985) for a similar discussion.

Comment: This is completely bogus. Mawk and gawk are about on par on POSIX compliance (though the lack of support for character classes in mawk is a bug). The error here has nothing to with the choice of awk implementation.